# Improve the Close FAQ

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

The Vote-to-Close dialog contains a number of links to the #close section of the FAQ, but that part of the FAQ is really just the same text as in the dialog box, plus a statement of what closure is.  It appears to be relevant to the *Closee* but not the Closer.

There is a link in the existing FAQ to the useful *[How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)* page, but its in this context:

> See How to Ask for guidance on editing **your** question to improve it.

In most cases the Closer will not be the OP.

The FAQ links in the Vote-to-Close dialog should be relevant to the *Closer* - informing their voting process.

So, my suggestion is to write (probably by collating some meta posts) a FAQ section specifically aimed at Closers.  This should have expanded notes for each close reason, and ideally, a link to the (a?) FAQ section on editing-to-improve posts if they might be salvaged and reopened.

I'm happy to try to draft something, but would welcome suggestions in respect of this.

Comment: Related: [A guide to moderating crypto.stackexchange yourself - close voting](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/129/a-guide-to-moderating-crypto-stackexchange-yourself-close-voting) - It's been posted on at least a dozen Metas, and I think it's very close to what you're looking for.